PrismaClientInitializationError: Prisma Client could not locate the Query Engine for runtime "linux-musl-openssl-3.0.x"
I'm trying to deploy a nextjs application (Supastarter) using docker image.
This is the content of my docker file
FROM node:20-alpine AS base
ENV PNPM_HOME="/pnpm"
ENV PATH="$PNPM_HOME:$PATH"
RUN corepack enable

# ---- Base Build Stage ---- #
FROM base AS builder
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN apk update
WORKDIR /
RUN pnpm add -g turbo
COPY . .
RUN turbo prune web --docker

# ---- Installer Stage ---- #
FROM base AS installer
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN apk update
WORKDIR /

# Install Prisma globally
RUN pnpm add -g prisma zod-prisma-types @prisma/client

# Copy lockfile and install dependencies
COPY .gitignore .gitignore
COPY --from=builder /out/json/ .
COPY --from=builder /out/pnpm-lock.yaml ./pnpm-lock.yaml

# Install dependencies specifically for the database and all other packages
ENV CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=0
# RUN pnpm install --filter database...
RUN pnpm install

# Copy the rest of the build files
COPY --from=builder /out/full/ .
COPY turbo.json turbo.json

# ---- Prisma Client Generation ---- #
WORKDIR /packages/database

# COPY turbo.json /packages/database/turbo.json

COPY .gitignore .gitignore
COPY --from=builder /out/json/ .
COPY --from=builder /out/pnpm-lock.yaml ./pnpm-lock.yaml

RUN pnpm install

# Ensure the DATABASE_URL is set before running Prisma generate
ENV DATABASE_URL "HIDDEN"

# Generate Prisma client for the database package
RUN pnpm run db:generate

# Ensure node_modules and other necessary files are copied
COPY ./apps/web/next.config.js ./next.config.js
COPY ./apps/web/next-env.d.ts ./next-env.d.ts
COPY ./apps/web/package.json ./package.json


# Install dependencies for the web package
# RUN pnpm install

# ---- Build the Web Application ---- #
WORKDIR /
COPY .gitignore .gitignore
COPY --from=builder /out/json/ .
COPY --from=builder /out/pnpm-lock.yaml ./pnpm-lock.yaml

RUN pnpm add @content-collections/next @prisma/client --workspace-root

RUN pnpm prisma generate

RUN pnpm turbo run build --filter=web...

# ---- Runner Stage ---- #
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /

# Setup nodejs user
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs
USER nextjs

# Copy over necessary files from the installer stage
COPY --from=installer /apps/web/next.config.js .
COPY --from=installer /apps/web/package.json .

# Copy static assets and the compiled server files
COPY --from=installer --chown=nextjs:nodejs /apps/web/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=installer --chown=nextjs:nodejs /apps/web/.next/static ./apps/web/.next/static
COPY --from=installer --chown=nextjs:nodejs /apps/web/public ./apps/web/public

USER nextjs

# Expose the port for the app
EXPOSE 3000

# Environment variables
ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"
ENV DATABASE_URL "HIDDEN"
ENV MIGRATION_DATABASE_URL "HIDDEN"
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL "HIDDEN"
ENV RESEND_API_KEY "HIDDEN"
ENV EDGE_STORE_ACCESS_KEY "HIDDEN"
ENV EDGE_STORE_SECRET_KEY "HIDDEN"

# Start the application
CMD ["node", "apps/web/server.js"]

Everything works fine except i get this error after running the docker image and i try accessing the website url

I've tried installing openssl in my docker container as given HERE
that doesnt even work. Please what can i do ?
I'm running on cloudpanel with Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
